# Extract csv data from a Response object in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, request, buffer, response, puppeteer

I am able to sucessfully recieve a response by using puppeteer's: `page.waitForResponse(url)`.

When I try `await response.buffer()` i get this error: `Error: Protocol error (Network.getResponseBody): No resource with given identifier found`

The response is type is correct (`'text/csv; charset=utf-8'`) and running `response.ok()` outputs `true`

Is there another way of possibly extracting the csv data? the document is downloaded with the correct datain the browser with `headless: false`.

Here is my code:

```js
await page.click('#export')
const firstResponse = await this.page.waitForResponse(page.url());
console.log(await firstResponse.ok()) // true
console.log(await firstResponse.buffer()) // Error: Protocol error (Network.getResponseBody): No resource with given identifier found
```